# How to set the parent of an entity as a property?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

i want to do something like this:

```
e = Employee(key_name = 'john',name='john the first')
e.put()
a = Address(key_name='addr_john',street='66th street')
a.parent = e;
a.put();

addr = Address.gql("WHERE ANCESTOR IS :1", e).fetch(1) #len(addr)==0
```

But it doesn't works, it just works if i set the parent in the constructor.

```
a = Address(key_name='addr_john',street='66th street',parent=e)
```

But i don't want to do it, i need to do it after i create the object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parent for an entity can only be set during its creation, so only in a constructor of `db.Model` subclass instance. Attempting to assign to `parent` attribute of `db.Model` instance would result in its `parent()` function being overwritten, but the actual parent for corresponding datastore entity will not be changed.

If you have relationship that cannot be established during creation of child object, you should consider coding it as ordinary property.
Alternatively (if you cannot afford not having the parent-child relation due to transactions you need) you could try to defer creation of child object until you can determine which parent it should have. Since apparently you also use the parent data (i.e. `name` of `Employee`) to establish a `key_name` for child entity, this approach seems to make sense. (Key names, like parents, can also be set only during entity's creation).

Comment: Thanks Xion. I want to create a bunch of objects that all of them are children from a given ParentObject. So i want to make put_async on that ParentObject, and create those ChildObjects, and after that assign the parent (maybe block a little to get the result). So bad it can't be done. Do you know some way to re-assign a key to a model? Becouse i could create the Key and assign to the ChildObject after everything happens.

Comment: @santiagobasulto: it's impossible to change the Key of an object after it's been created, except by creating a new entity with the same data and deleting the old entity.

Comment: Thank you both. I will have to keep doing everything the same way i was.

Comment: You may want to look into `db.allocate_ids` functions. Using it, you can preallocate an ID for your `ParentObject`, generate a key from it and assign it as parent of you `ChildObject` while the `ParentObject` is still being asynchronously put. Just make sure the `ParentObject` has been written before you attempt to put `ChildObject`s. However, since `db.allocate_ids` is in itself an RPC call, it doesn't seem to be worth the hassle if it is to generate only one ID.